# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar la librería rut-chile 2.0.1 en un data frame python - pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Como se puede usar la librearía rut-chile 2.0.1 con un dataframe que tiene una columna de ruts. Existe alguna forma de verificar con el rut los nombres u obtener los nombres.
¿Existe alguna página dónde conectarse con python para verificar rut y nombres, usando un data frame? Me podrían dar algunos ejemplos

Gracias

PL